# Form Won't Redirect to Response Page

Tags: php, validation, redirect

Created a form, and it checks for errors with php, but after a successful submission it doesn't redirect to the response page I created (thanks.php). It redirects to the same contact page with the same header and page format, but no actual text and the bodytext div doesn't show up. I just need it to redirect to the response page that I created. Any help?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
 $firstnameerror=$browsererror=$sexerror=$dateerror=$visiterror=$judgementerror=$emailerror=$emailconfirmerror="";

 if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $browser = htmlspecialchars($_GET['browser']);
        $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET['firstname']);
        $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_GET['lastname']);
        $sex = htmlspecialchars($_GET['sex']);
        $date = htmlspecialchars($_GET['date']);
        $visit = htmlspecialchars($_GET['visit']);
        $judgement = htmlspecialchars($_GET['judgement']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']);
        $emailconfirm = htmlspecialchars($_GET['emailconfirm']);

        echo "<p>form submitted</p>";

        if (isset($browser) && isset($firstname) && isset($lastname) && isset($sex) && isset($date) && isset($visit)
          && isset($judgement) && isset($message) && isset($email) && isset($emailconfirm)){
            echo "<p>all fields were submitted</p>";}

        if (empty($firstname)){
            $firstnameerror .= "<div class= 'error'>First name is missing</div>";}

        if (empty($browser)){
            $browsererror .= "<div class= 'error'>Tell us where you're from</div>";}

        if (empty($sex)){
            $sexerror .= "<div class= 'error'>Gender is missing</div>";}

        if (empty($date)){
            $dateerror .= "<div class= 'error'>Date is missing</div>";}

        if (empty($visit)){
            $visiterror .= "<div class= 'error'>Tell us what you visited</div>";}

        if (empty($judgement)){
            $judgementerror .= "<div class= 'error'>Tell us what you thought</div>";}

        if (!empty($email) && empty($emailconfirm)){
            $emailerror .= "<div class= 'error'>Please confirm your email</div>";}

        if ($email != $emailconfirm){
            $emailconfirmerror .= "<div class='error'>Make sure your emails match.</div>";}

      if (empty($browsererror) && empty($firstnameerror) && empty($sexerror) && empty($dateerror) && empty($visiterror) && empty($judgementerror) && empty($emailerror)
          && empty($emailconfirmerror)){
          header('Location: thanks.php');
          exit();
        }
      }
?>

 <div class="bodytext">
  <form method="get" action="contact.php">
    <h2>Feedback</h2>
    <fieldset>
    <div>
    <label for="browser">Who are you?</label> <span style="font-size:10px;color:red">*Required</span><br>
    <input list="browsers" name="browser" placeholder="Click Arrow ->">
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Visitor">
        <option value="Town Resident">
          <option value="Cornell University Student">
            <option value="Ithaca College Student">
              <option value="Cornell University Professor">
                <option value="Ithaca College Professor">
                </datalist><?php echo $browsererror ?>
                </div><br><br>
                <div>
                <label for="firstname">First name</label> <span style="font-size:10px;color:red">*Required</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>"/><br>
                <?php echo $firstnameerror ?>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="lastname">Last name</label><br><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>"/>
              </div><br><br>
              <div>
                <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" checked>Male
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female<br>
                <?php echo $sexerror ?>
              </div><br>
              <div>
                <label for="date">Date of Visit</label> <span style="font-size:10px;color:red">*Required</span><br>
                <input type="date" name="date" min="2014-10-03" max="2014-10-05"><br>
                <?php echo $dateerror ?>
              </div><br>
              <div>
                <label for="visit">What did you visit?</label> <span style="font-size:10px;color:red">*Required</span><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Fairway Market" checked>Fairway Market<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Car Show">Car Show<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="First Peoples' Festival">First Peoples' Festival<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Concerts">Concerts<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Finger Lakes Cider Week">Finger Lakes Cider Week<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Apple Pie Bake-off">Apple Pie Bake-off<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Gallery Night">Gallery Night<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="visit" value="Other">Other<br>
                <?php echo $visiterror ?>
              </div><br>
              <div>
                <label for="judgement">What did you think?</label> <span style="font-size:10px;color:red">*Required</span><br>
                <input type="radio" name="judgement" value="Loved It" checked>Loved It<br>
                <input type="radio" name="judgement" value="Liked It">Liked It<br>
                <input type="radio" name="judgement" value="Neutral">No Opinion/Neutral<br>
                <input type="radio" name="judgement" value="Didn't Like It">Didn't Like It<br>
                <input type="radio" name="judgement" value="Hated It">Hated It<br>
                <?php echo $judgementerror ?>
              </div><br>
              <div>
                <label for="message">Suggestions/Improvements</label><br>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type your message here" value="<?php echo $message ?>"/></textarea><br><br>
               </div>
               <div>
                Do you want to be contacted about<br>future Downtown Ithaca Events?<br>
                <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type E-mail" value="<?php echo $email ?>"/><br>
                <label for="emailconfirm">Confirm:</label>
                <input type="email" name="emailconfirm" id="emailconfirm" placeholder="Confirm E-mail" value="<?php echo $emailconfirm ?>"/><br><br>
                <?php echo $emailerror ?><?php echo $emailconfirmerror ?></div>
                <input name="ResponseForm" type="hidden" value="thanks.php"/>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
          </div>
          <script src="JS/myscript.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect after echoing content. Remove this echo and it will redirect:

```
echo "<p>form submitted</p>";
```

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work, it still redirects me to the same page

Comment: Remove __ALL__ output if u want to do a redirect with `header`

Comment: If you're not echoing content, then the error is not in the redirect but in the error handling. Try to move the redirect right after the `if(isset($_GET['submit']))` to see if the redirect works, if it works you have an error before or in the if where you check for errors.

Comment: All output is removed but it still doesn't redirect to the header

Comment: You can't have output before the header. Not to create additional work but you should have jquery to validate the fields. You should also put "echo "<p>form submitted</p>";" in your landing page.

Comment: @unixmiah U should always perform backend validation and never rely on clientside validation !!!!

Comment: @Greg be sure to enable all error_reporting and turn on display errors! you'll see some warnings which generate output

Comment: And don't action your form with GET. They don't make monitors wide enough to take that length of url

Comment: @DarkBee this is how I used to think until new front-end technologies came out. I'll go back to my old ways.

Answer (score 0):

`empty` only triggers if a variable does not exist or is set to `false`. If you create a variable with no value, `empty` will not trigger.

So, change your conditional statements from:

```
empty($browsererror)
```

To:

```
!$browsererror
```

Answer (score -1):

You **can't** use `header("location: somewhere.php");` after any output, it doesn't matter if is a space or just H or Hi, you just can't use it.

You have to handle the form data **before** show any data. Also, **you should validate with JS**, because of this way you don't have to make an innecesarias request to the server and help the server to receive adequate data and remember, **don't output** anything before call `header("location: somewhere.php");`

Comment: -1 for claiming serverside validation is slow. Never ever trust client side validation! What if I turn off my javascript? Then I just can enter whatever I want?

Comment: No no no no no and no.

Comment: Well ok, i undestand we have to use a validation, but it is slow, you also could do than if the JS is disabled the user can't use the page and instruct the user how to enable js for use the page

Comment: With JS validation anybody could inject or even totally rewrite any validation. Incredibly bad practice.